# Batch file to read lines from text file

Tags: batch-file

i am new to batch scripting and i would like your help for the following:
i have a text file which looks like:

```
E8-40-F2-3C-2E-FD,w7-301
E8-40-F2-AC-D4-E0,w7-302
E8-40-F2-AB-D9-F6,w7-303
E8-40-F2-3C-2F-2D,w7-304
E8-40-F2-AB-D0-D7,w7-305
```

my goal is to serach for a `MAC` address if exists in the file and if so to print the name after the comma that belongs to this MAC:

E.g: i want to look for `E8-40-F2-AC-D4-E0`(it would be represented as a variable and not as string)
and it will print: `w7-302`

Thanks for you help
Regards,
Mike

Comment: if MAC address exists as a lan card on the same machine or if MAC address exists in some local network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alternatively use `findstr`:

```
@echo off
:: You can replace 'address' with your own variable name
set address=E8-40-F2-AC-D4-E0

:: You would have to replace 'C:\mac.txt' with the actual path
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('findstr /B /L "%address%" "C:\mac.txt"') do echo %%a
```

This solution is a lot faster and can be easily modified to include multiple files, multiple addresses and to include more/less detail regarding the search results.

Comment: could you help me with one more thing please
i am using "getmac" to retrieve a local address and save it to a file "mymac" and it looks like this:
1
2 F0-79-59-62-20-EB   \Device\Tcpip_{F4744941-2A87-4DFA-A61B-393B8830B0C3}    

first line is empty and it starts in the second with no space in the beginning 

how can i edit this file so i will only have the MAC in the first row?

Answer (score 0):

**Not tested**.You need to change the path to your file:

```
@echo off
set mac_file=c:\mac_adr.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%mac_file%") do (
  set "%%a=%%b"
)

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('arp -a') do (
   if defined %%a (
     set %%a
     rem -- or
     rem -- for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%z in ('set %%a') do echo %%z
   )
)
```

this should print both mac address and the `wX-XXX` if you want to print only the second part uncomment the `rem --`  lines and comment `set %%a`